# using class.getResource to load a JSON file in java

Tags: java, json

I am starting to dwell into the use of JSON files for various reasons, but I am having trouble parsing them from the resource folder. I used the getResource before for getting images from the resource folder like so:

```
 ImageIcon a_1 = new ImageIcon(FrontHand.class.getResource("/Images/player_sprite.gif"));
 player_sprite = a_1.getImage();
```

but I cannot seem to get the same method of receiving files working for the JSON file. I have tried adding the same method to getting the JSON file, but it recommended me to get the information as a string which I did then failed to find the file even though CTRL-clicking the path in the code reached the file.

Here is the parse function I want to turn into a getResource or getResource as stream type:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/taka/NetBeansProjects/DragonGame/src/Main/Resources/JSON/counter.txt"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

ps: when attempting to change the image getResource to the JSON file I did make it JSON/counter.txt/ instead of the full path

my attempted code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(String.valueOf(FrontHand.class.getResource("/JSON/counter.txt"))));
```

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MgOm.jpg

Comment: Could you post the exact error message ?

Comment: Posting exact exception/error encountered along with your post, will be helpful in getting it resolved quickly.

Comment: will do, give me a minute